# c# Provide packet source in pcap.net

Tags: c#, pcap.net

I am following Pcap.net tutorials from its wiki on github. I tried to run code from here:

https://github.com/PcapDotNet/Pcap.Net/wiki/Pcap.Net-Tutorial-Handling-offline-dump-files

I didn't understand the following part:

```
if (args.Length != 1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("usage: " + Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()[0] + " <filename>");
            return;
        }
```

But I run this code and Bingo, nothings happen (no output).

I tried to figure out and found that `args` has the value "0".

I comment `return` command and it start working fine till I got `IndexOutOfBound` exception here:

```
using (PacketDumpFile dumpFile = communicator.OpenDump(args[0]))
```

Did I missed any thing?

Comment: I didn't expect to talk myself all the time on "stackoverflow".

Comment: Still nothing, I am going to select my own answer as accepted.

Comment: And no change in my Repo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This program require 1 argument (i.e. 'filename'in this case) that you should pass through command line.

Compile the code and run the program through command line with argument value.

**For Example:**

In CLI  `>MyProg.exe fileNmae`